# HalvingGridSearchCV

Tags: machine-learning, regression, feature-selection, random-forest, grid-search

Is there a way to get Feature importance from sklearn`s HalvingGridSearchCV?

For example:
[image]

[image]

Is there any way to access the feature importance? Please help me up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the importance of hyperparameter matching method functions, only models. To get the best model, use the best_estimator_ attribute or train the model again using the best_params_ attribute from HalvingGridSearchCV.